# Trying to CSS style a specific <tr> that contains a word

Tags: javascript, css

I have a `<tr>` which sometimes contains the word Discount in the first of two `<td>`'s, and when it does contain the word discount I'd like a class to be given to the entire table row, and when it doesn't contain the word discount I would like it to remain classless.

Can't seem to figure out the right way to do this with javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean the word *discount* would be in any one of those (or) would be in the first `td` among the two?

Comment: Discount is in the first td among the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have the script in `<script>` tag in `<head>`, use it like below:

```
function styleRow() {
    var table = document.getElementById('shopping-cart-totals-table');
    var row = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
        console.log('ok');
        if (row[i].getElementsByTagName('th').length > 0)
        {
            var inputTxt = row[i].getElementsByTagName('th')[0].textContent;
            if (inputTxt.toLowerCase().indexOf('discount') != -1) 
                row[i].className = 'red';
        }
    }
}
window.onload = styleRow;
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/aH2WG/)

Comment: The tr still has no class. I put this in between <script></script> tags in the header, yes?

Comment: if you put this in `<head>` you have to put it in a function and call it `onload`. Else you can put it within `<script>` tag just before `</body>` (to make sure the elements are available when the script is executed).

Comment: It's still not working for me. It shows up in the source in the header as you posted it in the second box, but the tr is still blank. I'm thinking maybe Magento is interfering here or something.

If you want to see it in action as I have it you'd have to add http://gateopenerking.com/store/gto-pro-sw-3200xls-dual-operator-for-use-with-sw-3000xls-650lb16ft.html to the cart. Discount is currently large but it's from CSS & nth-row(even) which means when discount isn't there tax is gigantic and red. Oy. Sorry. Struggling with this.

Comment: @Xander: It seems like Discount is in <th> and not <td>. Try changing the 'td' in the code to 'th' and in addition the `tr` seems to be inside `tbody` also, so I have modified the code in the answer (second block). Try it and let me know.

Comment: @Xander: Duh...there are more. You have three `table`s in the page so `[0]` will not work as expected. Instead you have to access it by `id`. The table's `id` seems to be `shopping-cart-totals-table`. Check the edit in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
// get all <tr>
var theTRs = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for(i=0; i<theTRs.length; i++) {
    // get first two <td>
    var theTDs = theTRs[i].getElementsByTagName('td');
    var theFirstTD = theTDs[0];
    var theSecondTD = theTDs[1];
    // check if one of those <td> contains "discount", if yes, add class
    if(theFirstTD.textContent.indexOf("discount") != -1 || theSecondTD.textContent.indexOf("discount") != -1) {
        theTRs[i].className = "yourclassgoeshere";
    }
}
```

Comment: The tr still has no class. I put this in between <script></script> tags in the header, yes?

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

**Vanilla JavaScript:**

```
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('table tr td');
for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++)
{
    if(tds[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase() == "discount") {
        tds[i].parentNode.setAttribute('class', 'discount');
    }
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/zqPHC/1/)

**jQuery:**

```
$('table tr td:contains("Discount")').closest('tr').addClass('discount');
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/zqPHC/)

### Update:

Since jQuery's `:contains` also matches the word `nodiscount`, so this is an alternative of `jQuery` solution and better, IMO

```
$('table tr td').filter(function(){
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText).toLowerCase().match(/^discount$/);
}).parent('tr').addClass('discount');
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/zqPHC/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tr td')each(function(){
        if($(this).text().indexOf('Discount')>0)
            $(this).closest('tr').addClass('someClass');
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure if user is looking at jQuery as an option as it is not added in tags.

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to set up the class with `css` and add the styling you want the discount row to have. Something like this:

```
tr.discount-row {
    //your style here
}
```

Then the code:

```
var table = document.getElementById("MyDiscountTab"); //this is the table
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); //these are the rows

for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) { // do this for each row
    var col = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0]; //and this is the first column/cel of a row
    if (col.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf("discount") > -1) {
        rows[i].setAttribute("class", "discount-row");// adding the class
    }
}
```

And yes, this goes on the `<script></script>` in the header inside window's `onload` function like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  //code here
};
```

or maybe like this:

```
myFunction = function () {
    //code here
}

...

window.onload = function() {
  myFunction();
};
```

Here's some [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hjvCM/) you can check.

Comment: The table has no ID and I can't give it one.

Comment: then change document.getElementById("MyDiscountTab") to document.getElementsByTagName("table")[index-number] or document.getElementsByClassName("class-name")[index-number] if the table already has a class.